# how to convert UIStoryBoard code to xib file code

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xib

I create one application that has side menu (like facebook) and this menu open fron left side.

I want create this app with xib file and I help from one project. in that project exist UIStoryBoard and I have problem with this code :

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    self.leftVC = (LeftVC*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftVC"];;

    [self.navigationController.view.superview insertSubview:self.leftVC.view belowSubview:self.navigationController.view];
```

I want to use xib file instead storyboard. (my xib file is : LeftVC.xib)

Comment: Do you have a view controller with identifier LeftVC or is it just the xib's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hop you have corresponding  VC for LeftVC. Then do like

```
LeftVC *leftVC = [LeftVC alloc][initWithNibName:@"LeftVC" bundle:nil];  
[self.navigationController.view.superview insertSubview:self.leftVC.view belowSubview:self.navigationController.view];
```

Comment: when run app crashed and show me this page :// BSD License. Author: jano@jano.com.es

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: I use this code : LeftVC *leftVC = [[LeftVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"LeftVC" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController.view.superview insertSubview:leftVC.view belowSubview:self.navigationController.view];

Comment: are you using any externa library Do you have a navigationController?